# Clang to g++/GCC linking on m1 MBP

Tags: gcc, clang, apple-m1

[location of g++/GCC installed through by Homebrew[][1]][1]

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njug0.jpg**

---

```
navinkarunanithi@Navins-MacBook-Pro bin % rm g++
rm: g++: Permission denied
navinkarunanithi@Navins-MacBook-Pro bin % rm g++
rm: g++: Permission denied
navinkarunanithi@Navins-MacBook-Pro bin % ln -s g++-11 g++
ln: g++: File exists
navinkarunanithi@Navins-MacBook-Pro bin % g++
clang: error: no input files
navinkarunanithi@Navins-MacBook-Pro bin %
```

I have been trying linking gcc on m1 mbp but I have tried and failed .
gcc/g++ are in the same location as clang and I don't know how to override them .
please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a long time of searching I found a blog and now I was able to change it

https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/88063

so if you have installed g++ and gcc via home-brew you can use this command

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/g++-10 /usr/local/bin/
```